# How to call a typescript function from kendo template

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, typescript

I'm using Typescript and Kendo UI in my project. It worked fine until I want to customize the grid data by calling a function in the grid template. I updated the template to:

```
    <td>#= Simple(Id) #</td>
```

and added the function. It worked fine and displayed id in the cell.

```
<script>
    function Simple(id) {
        return id;
    }
</script>
```

The problem is I want to define Simple method in my Typescript class, but I can't get the scope of the function right. I tried to add it to my view class or dataSource, but nothing worked. The columns can't be rendered since the function is undefined. I don't want to define a global function. How can I bind a function defined in a typescript class to the grid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to call function in typescript from kendo template in kendotreelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384524/not-able-to-call-function-in-typescript-from-kendo-template-in-kendotreelist)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, what is passed to the template is an instance of a Kendo Model, so you'd have to define your method on `kendo.data.Model.fn`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it in a global context.

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass {
    //Do wathever you want
    //Template
    <td>#= Simple(Id) #</td>
    }
}

function Simple(id) {
        return id;
}
```

reference: [Not able to call function in typescript from kendo template in kendotreelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384524/not-able-to-call-function-in-typescript-from-kendo-template-in-kendotreelist)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but I have had similar issues and found a way around it.

in your cshtml file. you need to reference your javascript file thats generated, and then instantiate the object like so

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Notifications/notifications.js")"> </script>
<script>
    var fe_head = new Fe.Upsm.Head();
    var fe_n = new Fe.Upsm.Notifications();
</script>
```

Then in your typescript file I am using namespaces and classes like so

```
namespace Fe.Upsm {
    export class Notifications {
        .. methods
        NotificationsGrid_onDataBound(){
        ... code here
        }
        ... more methods

    }
}
```

in the Razor

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<NotificationViewModel>()
      .Name("NotificationsGrid")
      .AutoBind(false)
      .NoRecords("No notifications yet")
      .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table" })
      .Events(m => m.DataBound("fe_n.NotificationsGrid_onDataBound")) // because you have instantiated your object you then qualify it the object name you have newed up the instance of and the method
..... more grid values
```

Hopefully this resolves anyone elses issues if they come across it