# Not able to call function in typescript from kendo template in kendotreelist

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, typescript, kendo-ui

> Kendo TreeList code in class A (typescript file): I have given call to a function from kendo template.

```
export class A{                        
            drillDownDataSource: any;        
            constructor() {               
                    this.GetStatutoryIncomeGridViewData();
            }    
            GetStatutoryIncomeGridViewData() {        
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Controller/Action/',
                    data: stfilterData,
                    success: function (data) {
                   $("#grid").kendoTreeList({
                    dataSource: data,                                       
                    columns: [
                 { field: "Transaction1",
template:kendo.template("#=FormatNumberToEn(Transaction1)#").bind(this) },
                                        }                    
                });
            });

      public FormatNumberToEn(value) { }
    }
    }
```

Getting error `function FormatNumberToEn is undefined`

Comment: you should post the entire class A and any modules it might be belonging too. It matters when you are trying to call the function.

Comment: @toskv added the class

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use functions in KendoUI templates you have to define them in the global (JavaScript-)Scope. ([Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#handle-external-templates-and-expressions))

Just extract the `FormatNumberToEn` function from the class `A`.

```
export class A { 
    /* class definition */ 
}
function FormatNumberToEn(value) { /* function logic */ }
```

Alternatively defining your function as `static` and calling `A.FormatNumberToEn()` inside the template might also work. (Can't test it right now as I'm on mobile.)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped to solve the same problem.